# JS Ripple effect to IMG not to background

Tags: jquery

I am trying ot alter jquery.ripples (https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/) to use the ripple effect on an image itself, not the background.  I've tried numerous things to no avail.  Any guidance, or advice for another method would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin doesn't support images, so you have two options:

1. Wait for author to add that functionality (or someone else, who fork this project), or
2. Make a shortcut - for each image you want to use this effect, you need to create div on the top (position:absolute, z-index:10; width and height equal to dimensions of image) and copy image's src and set it as div's background. Then u can use this effect like in example.

Little example:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('img.ripples-image').each(function() {
    $image = $(this);
    $image.wrap('<div class="ripples-wrapper"></div>').after('<div class="ripples-img" style="background-image:url(\''+ $image.attr('src') +'\')"></div>');
  });
  
  // Set effect
  $('.ripples-img').ripples();
});
```

```css
.ripples-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block; 
}
.ripples-wrapper img{
  display:block;
  visibility:hidden; /* Hidden, but keep place */
}
.ripples-img{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:10;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ripples/0.4.2/jquery.ripples.js"></script>

<img class="ripples-image" src="http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/wisconsin.golf/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/1/23/1233a6ba-d0d8-11e5-9a3c-fbcece8553f7/56bcafd946c28.image.jpg?resize=400%2C400" alt="StackOverflow logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this ,Upload your photo on https://imgur.com/ then after upload finishes press right click on image then copy image address and put it into your code just like this: background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/yourphotolink.jpg) 
NOTE:after copying the link check that your link ends with .jpg or .png if it ends with .jpg?1 delete ?1 so your link ends with .jpg

i don't know why jquery ripple effect doesn't support ordinary photos but this will solve your problem